# Authenticate 3rd partiy services to my WebAPI service

Tags: c#, .net, security, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I have a WebAPI service that is being called from other services. I need to protect it.

1) How to protect my service ?

2) I am hosting it in IIS, so do I need to look at OAuth 2.0 or just use Basic Authentication using SSL ?(but not sure of how 3rd party services authenticate with my service).

3) When should I use OAuth 2.0 with WebAPI

4) What authentication method do I need, in order to give access to the service from a iOS/Android/WindowsPhone application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your requirements are.

If those other services are 3rd party web services that you only want to allow to call into your service, you could give them an [API key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface_key) (which is in principal the same as a password).

If those services need to call your service with the security context of the user calling their service (delegated authorization), you should probably look into OAuth 2.0 which deals with that scenario.

You could use an open source authorization server like [Thinktecture](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/) or expose a [token issuing endpoint](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/01/15/using-json-web-tokens-with-katana-and-webapi.aspx) in your service using Katana middleware.

Comment: how to deal with smart client apps trying to access the API ? OAuth 2.0 as well ?